# Secure asp.net core web api using authorize attributes + identity Server 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, identityserver4

I managed to set up an Identity Server 4 using `is4aspid` from [their templates](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Templates) and it seems to be working fine. Now I'm trying to protect a Web Api using Asp.net Core 2.0. The `Authorize` seems to be working, but when I try to use `[Authorize(Roles ="Admin")]`  in my controller method it won't work.

I watched [this video](https://youtu.be/EJeZ3YNnqz8?t=1752) and tried to do what they did, but I can't find a good chunk of the code they use, like `AuthorizationProviderClient` or `app.UseAuthorizationProvider()`

This is the `Startup.cs` `ConfigureServices` method of my Identity Server:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer (Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc();

        services.Configure<IISOptions>(iis =>
        {
            iis.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Windows";
            iis.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
        });

        var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
        })
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApis())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();

        if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("need to configure key material");
        }

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddGoogle(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = "xxxx-xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
                options.ClientSecret = "xxxxx";
            });
    }
```

And this is the config class:

```
public static class Config
{
    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
    {
        return new IdentityResource[]
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile()
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApis()
    {
        return new ApiResource[]
        {
            //new ApiResource("api1", "My API #1") 
            new ApiResource("api1", "My API #1") { UserClaims = { "role" }  }
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            // https://www.scottbrady91.com/Angular/SPA-Authentiction-using-OpenID-Connect-Angular-CLI-and-oidc-client
            new Client {
                ClientId = "angular_spa",
                ClientName = "Intranet Web App",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                AllowedScopes = new List<string> { "openid", "profile", "api1" },
                RedirectUris = new List<string> { "http://localhost:4200/auth-callback", "http://localhost:4200/silent-refresh.html" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string> { "http://localhost:4200/" },
                AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string> { "http://localhost:4200" },
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And this is the Startup.cs ConfigureServices of my WebApi:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvcCore()
            .AddAuthorization()
            .AddJsonFormatters();

        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ApiName = "api1";
                options.EnableCaching = false;
                options.RoleClaimType = System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Role;
            });
    }
```

And then the configure:

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }           

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

This is how the roles are in the database:
[image]

I got this API from their samples. When I send the Bearer token using Postman the Authorize attribute works fine, now I want to get the Roles to work as well. Am I missing a nuget package or something?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Please define "doesn't work".  Are you expecting it to deny you access and it isn't?  Or are you expecting access and it is denying you?  Something else entirely?

Comment: @Becuzz It's denying access to a user that has the role. Ex.: I'm using a token generated for alice and putting [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] and it's denying access.

Comment: What's putting the role claim in your JWT?  My guess is that it isn't being added to the token and thus doesn't have the role when you hit the controller.

Comment: @Becuzz depends, it's acting weird. See this line? new ApiResource("api1", "My API #1") { UserClaims = { "role" }  }

If I leave the UserClaims property, it will return a token with an extra role (the Employee). If I remove it won't put  the role property in the token

Comment: @AndréLuiz - so your token contains the claims: `name: alice, role: Employee`. Is this what you are saying?

Comment: I would separate the idea of roles away from IdentityServer as soon as possible. It's not flexible. It's not maintainable. It's not built for it and when the situation becomes more complicated, you'll find yourself in a heap of trouble. User authorization != identity. IdentityServer can be used in conjunction with authorization policies to create API scope boundaries and that makes sense. Putting user roles in JWTs does not.